# CodeIgniter - Nested foreach - show data by year

Tags: php, codeigniter, loops, foreach, nested-loops

I’m working on some script which must use year as exposed value. This information is saved in database and I have to pull it out, but that’s not the problem. I have to create list where are years exposed as main values. I was working on code, but I always get an error.

Controller:

```
$data['dbdata'] = $this->DBdata->serve_val('pc_year');
foreach ($data['dbdata']->result() as $data)
{
    $data['sheet'] = $this->DBdata->serve_val('pc');
    foreach ($data['sheet']->result() as $sht)
    {
        $data['vdata'][$data->idyr][$sht->idpc]['name'] = $sht->name;
        $data['vdata'][$data->idyr][$sht->idpc]['properties'] = $sht->properties;
    }
}
```

View:

```
foreach ($dbdata->result() as $data)
{
    echo $data->year."<br>";
    foreach ($sheet->result() as $sht)
    {
        echo $vdata[$data->idyr][$sht->idpc]['name']."<br>";
        echo $vdata[$data->idyr][$sht->idpc]['properties']."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```

Error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined offset: 1
```

How to do this correctly?

Comment: you should try naming your variables something besides data.  Youre overwriting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your controller, as you cant reassign a variable name

Controller:

```
$data['dbdata'] = $this->DBdata->serve_val('pc_year');
foreach ($data['dbdata']->result() as $result)
{
    $result['sheet'] = $this->DBdata->serve_val('pc');
    foreach ($result['sheet']->result() as $sht)
    {
        $data['vdata'][$result->idyr][$sht->idpc]['name'] = $sht->name;
        $data['vdata'][$result->idyr][$sht->idpc]['properties'] = $sht->properties;
    }
}
```

View:

```
foreach ($dbdata->result() as $data)
{
    echo $data->year."<br>";
    foreach ($sheet->result() as $sht)
    {
        echo $vdata[$data->idyr][$sht->idpc]['name']."<br>";
        echo $vdata[$data->idyr][$sht->idpc]['properties']."<br>";
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
```